# Apache POI: Excel changes my format string

Tags: java, excel, format, apache-poi, dataformat

I have this code:

```
 HSSFCellStyle styleCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();;
 CreationHelper ch = workbook.getCreationHelper();
 String format="# #";
 DataFormat dataFormat=ch.createDataFormat();
 styleCurrency.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat(format));
```

But when i check that cell in Excel's Format Dialogue it shows : `#\#` (It adds slash). Why?

I'm using Excel 2003.

Comment: A format string is not a regular expression.

Comment: @rgettman Ok! Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I found the ansewer by myself (as usual no help). To dysplay `# #` in Excel's Format Dialogue, add comma between #'s instead of white space. So `#,#` becames `# #`. Also, `0,00` becames `000` in Format Dialogue. To fix it add dot instead of comma, so `0.00` = `0,00`. Interesting why noone faced the same problem before as there's no info in internet.

Comment: Thank you! i had the format as: `# ##0,00 €` and it just automatically changed to `#\ ## 000\ \€` , so i had to change it to `#,##0.00 €` Very weird behavior